# Find & remove files that are uploaded through Cpanel x minutes ago, using SSH

Tags: ssh, command-line, terminal, find, delete

I have a Cpanel login of remote system into which I have uploaded a number of folders and files scattered throughout the structure.

But I remember that I did this a few minutes ago, roughly `x` minutes ago.

Now using `ssh` and logging into remote terminal of the system (to which I have uploaded files to) how can I find out which files were uploaded `x` minutes ago and remove them safely without altering any older files and directories ?

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

`find /path/to/directory -type f -cmin -20`

This will display all files created less than 20 minutes ago. If the list looks good, add `-delete` to the end to permanently erase these files.

Additionally, if you want to see files that were modified X minutes ago (eg if you overwrote some files), you can change -cmin to -mmin.

Comment: with `-delete` if it says `Directory not empty` then any other parameter to overcome this ?

Comment: This probably means that the directory wasn't emptied by the find, so there is some file in the folder that didn't match the -cmin requirement. Please try again with the `-type f` parameter I forgot to add on; this might leave you with some empty directories, but should satisfy deleting the files at least.

Comment: or use -depth...

Answer (score 1):

First run this command and verify the files:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -cmin -20
```

Once the files are displayed correctly, then use the following command to find & delete.

IMPORTANT: Give a correct path to the following command, giving wrong path, can screw your system.

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -cmin -20 -exec rm -rfv {} \;   ##without confirmation 

find /path/to/directory -type f -cmin -20 -exec rm -riv {} \; ##with confirmation .
```

Comment: please format your code for better readability of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -mmin +20 -exec rm -rfv {} \;
```

This will delete files in `/path/to/director` and under that, last modified 20+ minutes ago.